# Merge several eps files into one PDF

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, postscript

I have several hundred encapulated postscript files, and I want to merge them all into one big PDF. How can I do this?

Comment: Imagemagick's `convert` claims to do this.

Comment: @ott--: Feel free to add that as an answer.

Comment: I would be wary of using anything from ImageMagick to append vectorized images, such as the `convert +/- append` command. ImageMagick developers even [warn against](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#ps) using it on vectorized images (unless you don't mind rasterization, of course).

Comment: @madams I converted your answer to a comment since it wasn't actually answering the question. I saw in another comment that you're working on a solution. Please feel free to post it as a new answer and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 10):

Use a command like:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sOutputFile=sin_800.pdf *.eps
```

Comment: For those like me who didn't know what `gs` is, it's a command that calls the [GhostScript](http://www.ma.utexas.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?gs+1) _PostScript  and  PDF language interpreter and pre-viewer_.

Comment: This worked great, but it added them as individual pages. How might you create a single page document from `n` images?

Comment: @ryanjdillon: You might want to ask that as a separate question.